# Product Id for different app under same developer account

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am new to iOS.

Just design 2 apps under the same developer account. App 1 works fine. However, when I implement IAP for app2, I key in the same product id but system shows
*The product ID you entered has already been used. Enter a unique product ID and try again.*
The 2 app has different Bundle Id, SKU name, apple id. What should I do?

Comment: as per matt answer product id will generate on bundle id so if you have two app than both app bundle id will be difference as well as your bundle id will different than your product id must be difference.

Answer (score 0):

> I key in the same product id

Well don't.

> The 2 app has different Bundle Id, SKU name, apple id.

Irrelevant.

> What should I do?

Do just what the message said to do. Make up a different product ID for this IAP.